# SQLite - Select and Integer type

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a problem.

I want to access to an specific register in a SQLite table.

```
String[] campos = new String[] {"codInterno"};
            String[] arg2 = new String[] {strId};

            Cursor c = db.query("Incidentes", campos, "codReg=?", arg2, null, null, null);
```

so I need to have the register with field codInterno  where codReg = strId ... thats no problem.

Now i want to access an specific register, i have to put codInterno - 1,  and access using a select where codInterno = codInterno - 1 ..   This field is an integer, and always when i have to use a condition, i have to use an String array.

How can i put an integer parameter as condition in a SELECT?

Comment: Have you tried to but `myInt + ""` in the string array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your arg2 parameter you should use something like

```
String arg2[] = new { stdId, Integer.toString(codInterno) };
```